# How do i port my application across the different viewports

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtk3

I've been using GTK4 in C for some user interfaces in Linux (Ubuntu) but after searching the documentation for a long time, I'm unable to find any information regarding responsiveness of widgets across different screen sizes.

Here are some questions i'm looking answer for:

- How reponsiveness is done in GTK, do I have to listen for resize event and according to that change the position of all the child widgets or GTK provides some sort of layout container for handling this?
- How do I get screen width and height before even creating the window, so I can set the width and height of window accordingly?

Comment: I guess the most simple way should be to use the [dedicated gnome library](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libadwaita). Does this fit your needs ? (Sadly, its documentation is really poor...)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the window size before it is created is to do it before you call `gtk_widget_show` on it. (I have not tried that, it might not work) And it is mentioned in Simon Long's GTK2 tutorial that Gtk tries to resize its window elements intelligently automatically--you dont need to do anything. You mentioned a layout container. The most popularly used one is `GtkBox`.